# Is this curve an elliptic curve?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

Let there be a curve $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, which is an elliptic curve. Let there be another curve in  $\mathbb{C}^2$, say $\Gamma$'. such that I have a bijection between the two curves, f : $\Gamma$ $\to$ $\Gamma$', such that f(u,v) = (u,v').

Then is $\Gamma$' also an elliptic curve ?

Comment: That's the theorem relating the geometrical/topological genus with the Riemann-Roch genus (of the compact Riemann surfaces corresponding to the function field of your curves). Also you'll have to remove finitely many singular points from your curves, they will be biholomorphic to complex tori minus finitely many points.

Comment: I would say that there is no curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is an elliptic curve, since an elliptic curve is by definition complete.  Can you say exactly what definition of "curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$" and "elliptic curve" you are using?